# Javascript widget

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to Drupal and have gotten to this point because I merely want a test page for calendar widgets that I want to develop.  I am working with a product called Trumba which will generate a snippet of javascript and I'd like to see what that looks like on a web page.  At a high level, can I accomplish this with Drupal?  I think if the answer is "yes," I can begin the discovery process.  If the answer is "no," then you all will have saved me an immense amount of time.

Comment: short answer: yes

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do everything with drupal)

Try to use drupal_add_js() function to add your js.

Comment: Drupal can't do everything - only Chuck Norris can.